# Какие будут ограничения и проблемы в программах при работе с файлами на ПК при использовании Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Пишу простейший файловый менеджер.

Какие будут ограничения и проблемы в программах при работе с файлами на ПК при использовании Xamarin?

Или лучше использовать Mono?

Comment: У Xamarin насколько я понимаю внутри как раз Mono, так что непонятно, в чём разница.

Comment: Да не какой разницы. Как и в принципе ограничений.